# Custom DataModel in Xml View

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

How can I bind custom data models in sapui5 xml view.
What I want is create multiple views and bind different and multiple(more than one for each) data models.

I can do this in js view by setting view id and jsonmodel names similar, for example:

View id= Customer1, Model Name = Customer1Sales, Customer1Tax. Then I just add Sales and Tax to view id than give this path to bind.

So how can I make something like this in xml view.

Comment: You have to give names to your models then you can bind as many as you want. Pls provide some code sample for more insight :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I can make as you said in js views, I mean how can I make that in xml view. How can I get the view name, modify it and set as path value.

Comment: The syntax for named model binding in xml is : {Customer1Sales>/mySalesProperty}
 {Customer1Tax>/myTaxProperty}

Comment: Yes I use it as just you said, but what I will do if I have a model as Customer2, how I create a view for this?

Comment: I mean what should I do for a multiple models situation.

Comment: I do not understand the problem :p just bind the properties from as many models as you want :o

Comment: But how? Are you saying copy the same code over and over again?

Comment: I should show multiple copies of this view in the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152021/discussion-between-brahim-ozcan-and-ash-kander).